# XSLT Gouping, for-each and implicated loop. How to eliminate duplicates?

Tags: xslt, loops, foreach, grouping, duplicates

Hope find a guru's help to figure out the next problem.

I have two xml files. Firts one here (**text.xml**):

```
<text>
<ref>Author1, Title1, Date1</ref>
<ref>Author75, Title75, Date2</ref>
<ref>Author2, Title2, Date2</ref>
<ref>Author3, Title3, Date3</ref>
<text>
```

And the second one like this (**list.xml**):

```
<list>
<bibl xml:id="1"><author>Author1</author><date>Date1</date></bibl>
<bibl xml:id="2"><author>Author2</author><date>Date2</date></bibl>
<bibl xml:id="3"><author>Author3</author><date>Date3</date></bibl>
</list>
```

I want to query **text.xml** and check against **list.xml** to add @xml:id (from **list.xml**) to `<ref>` (from **text.xml**) wich contain same Author and Date. If not, then just copy original `<ref>`.

So I want to obtain:

```
<ref xml:id="1">Author1, Title1, Date1</ref> 
<ref>Author75, Title75, Date2</ref>
<ref xml:id="2>Author2, Title2, Date2</ref>
etc.
```

My **XSLT** identify well all correpondence:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ref">
        <xsl:variable name="ref" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="document('list.xml')//bibl">
            <xsl:variable name="bibl" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="author" select="author"/>
            <xsl:variable name="date" select="date"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($ref, $author) and contains($ref, $date)">
                    <ref>
                        <xsl:attribute name="xml:id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$bibl/@xml:id"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$ref"/>
                    </ref>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$ref"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, then there aren't correpondence it's not just copy right `<ref>`, but copy all `<ref>` the number of time I have `<bibl>` nodes in the second file.

So problem is in `<xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="$ref"/></xsl:otherwise>`. 
Any ideas how I can obtain only this distinct value I need? I know it's must be very simple actually and I try key, generate-id, for-each-group, distinct-values, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a **ref** element for each iteration of the **for-each** loop whether there is a match or not.

What you need to do in this case is create the **ref** element outside of the **for-each** and then only create the id attribute for the matching element inside the loop

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ref">
      <xsl:variable name="ref" select="."/>
      <ref>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* "/>
         <xsl:for-each select="document('list.xml')//bibl">
            <xsl:variable name="bibl" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="author" select="author"/>
            <xsl:variable name="date" select="date"/>
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="contains($ref, $author) and contains($ref, $date)">
                  <xsl:attribute name="xml:id">
                     <xsl:value-of select="$bibl/@xml:id"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </ref>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<text>
   <ref xml:id="1">Author1, Title1, Date1</ref>
   <ref>Author75, Title75, Date2</ref>
   <ref xml:id="2">Author2, Title2, Date2</ref>
   <ref xml:id="3">Author3, Title3, Date3</ref>
</text>
```

However, your current method is not very efficient, as for each **ref** element you are iterating over all **bibl** elements. Another approach would be to extract the author and date from the **ref** elements, and then look up the **bibl** element directly

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ref">
      <xsl:variable name="author" select="normalize-space(substring-before(., ','))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="date" select="normalize-space(substring-after(substring-after(., ','), ','))"/>
      <ref>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* "/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="document('list.xml')//bibl[author=$author][date=$date]"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </ref>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="bibl">
      <xsl:attribute name="xml:id">
         <xsl:value-of select="@xml:id"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should also give the same results.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfect!

Totally agree that your second solution is much more elegant and efficient. But actually first xml file (**text.xml**) it's only a sample. The real `<ref>` it's something like `<ref>J. Smith, Book title, Publisher, 2001, p.211</ref>` or `<ref>Book title, eds. Smith John., 2005</ref>`, etc. So I don't really now where I can find Author or Date, all I know it's somewhere here.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
humm...too much focus on xsl syntax, i should have seen that earlier...
you have an implicated outer loop over each `ref` and an inner loop over each `bibl`. You generate one element for every `bibl` for every `ref` regardless of match or no match.
So, instead of the `xsl:otherwise` you need a check after the `for-each` loop to see if there was no match and do the `copy-of` if neccessary.

Not sure how to do the check, though..maybe using `position()` and `count()` of the generated `<ref>`s, sorry...don't have any more time to think about this right now.

<strike>not really an explanation, but a workaround:</strike>

```
<xsl:otherwise>
   <ref>
      <xsl:value-of select="$ref"/>
   </ref>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

My guess is that the problem lies in $ref, which is not a xpath expression at that moment (if i remember xsl-t correctly)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but still have a multiple duplicate of all <ref>. I guess it's most a problem of unique id of each $ref.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly my problem, you difine it very well. I tried yet <xsl:if> with contains() and not(contains()) instead <xsl:choose> but still have the same issue. Anyway, thanks for your time.